# Automating Google Definition Searches with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, scripting

I have a .doc file of words, one per line, that I'd like to have followed by " : " + the first definition grabbed from Google search. I then want this output to a .txt file.

I can put the original list into a .txt .CSV or whatever format necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently your question might be too broad to be answered. If you could edit your post to include what you've tried so far, that may help.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.